# Use UTF-8 in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

I use MySQL and PHP to store data in an Android app. I want to use UTF-8 in my database, and tables because the data is in English and Persian. This query is to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_notes` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `note_subject` varchar(22) NOT NULL,
  `note_date` text NOT NULL,
  `note_content` varchar(21000) NOT NULL,
  `note_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I use this code before connecting to the database:

```
$con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'UTF8'", $con);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8_general_ci", $con);
```

My problem is when I save the data to **note_content** and **note_subject**, the data is showing as "???????". And when I retrieve data to my android app again, the data is "????????".

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Just because your DB and your connection to the DB are set for utf-8, doesn't mean you're actually outputting that data into an UTF-8 environment. The entire pipeline has to be utf-8. If you use a different charset at any stage (mysql->php->phone->app), you'll likely get those mangled characters.

Comment: @MarcB How can i fix this? I should do things in my app by java for encoding?

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: @deceze Thanks but can't fix my problem.i change database same the link but not fixed

Comment: I found that problem is android app send data to internet same as ???????? and configuration of mysql and php codes are ok

Comment: What are you using to output your data? In PHP or in your Android App?